# Were there Black people in Japan in 1600?

Tags: japan, race

In [Where Are The Black People in 'Shogun'?](https://www.levelman.com/where-black-people-fx-shogun) claims:

> I don’t ask out of a desire to see representation when it wasn’t
> historically accurate. I inquire because there were Black people in
> Japan in 1600 and before, though Japan could teach Florida a thing or
> two about rewriting history.

Is this claim that there were Black people in Japan in 1600 when the story of Shogun takes place accurate?

Comment: This needs more context. Is the question "was there at least one single black person present in Japan in 1600?" Or is it about any noticeable percentage of the population being black? If the former, then it is not a good faith rebuttal against those who don't like that a movie or a video game is being populated by a historically inaccurate amount of "diversity". And the quote seems to want to do just that ("teach Florida a thing or two about rewriting history").

Comment: Nevermind, reading the original article makes it clear that it was written by an afrocentrist black-supremacists, with claims that all Samurai were partially black, and that the original inhabitants of Japan were African, etc.

Comment: How is this a 'relevant claim' or a 'reputable source'? Are we going to comb through the depths of Reddit or 4chan next?

Comment: The article says: "There is a consensus he was something other than pure Japanese, and he is often considered descended from the Ainu, the darker-skinned indigenous people of northern Japan who were subjected to forced assimilation and colonization." Not what you are asking about, but I just want to point out that this is the opposite of reality, which very much indicates wishful thinking on part of the writer, in that the Ainu are noted for being *more light-skinned* and have historically been considered moer European-looking than their neighbors.

Comment: The answer to this question as expressed in the title is about the same as “Were there humans on the Moon in the 20th century?”. Sure, a few came and went.

Comment: This publication self-describes as "LEVEL's mission is serving high-quality content to the grown Black man who is cultured, curious and looking to elevate or embrace the best version of himself.", established in 2019 by former Vibe staff. One of the writers goes by the pseudonym "The only black guy in the office", despite that the editor-in-chief is black. There is no Wikipedia page about this publication that I could find. This doesn't look like a remotely notable claim.

Comment: "the darker-skinned indigenous people of northern Japan" - the idea that indigenous people from the north of a country in the northern hemisphere, would be darker-skinned than [settlers from the same general part of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamato_people), is so absurd that the author can already be written off completely. Does this guy even know it *snows* there?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Just as there are people who insist that the Earth is flat and they ignore all evidence and logic against their views, there are some who insist that *their* ethnic group invented civilization and once ruled the entire world, but then got "erased" and information about it is being "kept hidden" by some secret conspiracy, and they don't really care about evidence or logical consistency either.

Comment: Ainu skin colour- see [Harvey & Lord-Skin colour of the Ainu of Hidaka, Hokkaido, Northern Japan](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/727704/) "...comparison of mean reflectance for Hokkaido Ainu and 'Central' Japanese with values predicted on the basis of world trends indicates that the differences are no greater than would be expected for two populations separated by over 7 degrees latitude and differing from one another in respect of temperature and humidity."

Comment: (In fact, the author's apparent default assumption that indigenous people would be "darker-skinned", neglecting countering evidence, is itself quite racist. Of course, I don't claim to know the though process that went into the claim, but it really doesn't look good.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, according to [Historical Context of Black Studies in Japan](https://hermes-ir.lib.hit-u.ac.jp/hermes/ir/re/8322/HJsoc0300200950.pdf):

> Confucian scholar Nishikawa Joken, for example, published *Kai tsusho ko* (1695), in which he wrote that the Zimbabweans were caribals. He heard this tall story from the Dutch merchants in Nagasaki who bought African natives as their servants.

[Nossa Senhora da Graça](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nossa_Senhora_da_Gra%C3%A7a_incident) is a specific example of a ship that brought Black slaves (and their Portuguese masters) to Japan; it dramatically exploded off the coast of Japan in 1610.

The earliest Africans in Japan arrived in the *previous* century. According to [Excluded Presence: Shoguns, Minstrels, Bodyguards, and Japan's Encounters with the Black Other](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/71097/1/40_15.pdf):

> In 1546 Portuguese captain Jorge Alvarez brought Africans to Japan. According to Alvarez, Japanese initial reaction to them was primarily one of curiosity: "They like seeing black people," he wrote in 1547, "especially Africans, and they will come 15 leagues just to see them and entertain them for three or four days". The most well-documented case is that Yasuke, a Mozambican brought to Japan by the Italian Jesuit Alessandro Valignano
> (1537 - 1606) who was presented to *daimyô* Oda Nobunaga in 1581.
>
> [...]
>
> Tohoku University professor Fujita Midori places the number of Africans temporarily residing in Japan during the 16th century at several hundred. Some came to Japan as slaves, servants, valets, sailors, soldiers, and interpreters. Their roles were not limited to serving Europeans. Like Yasuke, a number of Africans were employed by *daimyô* in various capacities, as soldiers, gunners, drummers, and entertainers. Whatever their position it appears they attracted the curious. During the Edo Period (1603 - 1867) a small number of black Africans lived in the Dutch settlement in Deshima. Despite the policy of national isolation, records reveal that black Africans mingled freely among the Japanese visitors and were allowed occasionally to leave the island, as were their European masters.

The Wikipedia page for [Yasuke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yasuke) (in Japan from 17 August 1579 to 21 June 1582) also provides some examples of artwork depicting a dark skinned man (or men) in Japan and some other solid references like [Chapter 2: Africans who came to Japan](https://www.ndl.go.jp/kaleido/e/entry/14/2.html).

Comment: What's a "caribal"?

Comment: @ShadowRanger Both are established English expressions. OED defines *Caribal* as "A Carib. (Sometimes regarded historically as equivalent to **cannibal**, n. 1b.)". And see ["tall story"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/tall-story) in Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure this fully addresses the question.  Although it shows that dark-skinned people were *known to* the Japanese of the day, and that some had visited Japan, the underlying premise being questioned is whether they were sufficiently commonplace in late 16th century Japan that an historically accurate depiction should have contained at least a few of them.  Or maybe not, given that the OP accepted this answer, but that's certainly how I understood the question.

Comment: @JohnBollinger : If you provide an answer that seems better reasoned, I'm happy to accept that.

Comment: How could someone write about _Zimbabweans_ in 1695? Of course [the ruins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Zimbabwe) in the inner of Africa existed, but it seems really unlikely that ruins were known in Japan, and even if they were, how could that lead to someone describing a group of people as _Zimbabweans_? Using the term _Zimbabwe_ for a political entity did not happen until 1979-1980, I believe.

Comment: I've gone through the 1695 text 華夷通商考 (_Ka-i Tsūshō Kō_, something like "China-Barbarian Trading Considerations") and the 1708 expanded edition. On page 37 of the 1695 edition [here](https://archive.wul.waseda.ac.jp/kosho/ne01/ne01_04067/ne01_04067_0002/ne01_04067_0002_p0037.jpg) and on page 48 of the expanded edition [here](https://lab.ndl.go.jp/dl/book/2535622?page=48&keyword=食), we see mention of cannibalism. (The 1708 one has a blue marker showing the rough location in the text.) The 1695 edition says that locals roast and eat the dead, while the 1708 just says they roast and eat people.

Comment: This is in a description of a country that Nishikawa calls カフリ (_Kafuri_), which [apparently](https://japanknowledge.com/tomonokai/card.html?id=123137&kw=モノモタパ) was another name for the [Kingdom of Mutapa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Mutapa), roughly corresponding geographically to modern Zimbabwe.  So while Nishikawa never uses the name "Zimbabwe", nor the older Japanese spelling 辛巴威 (_Shinbawi_), he _does_ talk about the same region, just using the name _Kafuri_.  (Pinging @JeppeStigNielsen.)